# unexpected result from boolean difference

Tags: modifiers

Source object is solid

[image: Source]
[image: Result]

Why???? v2.92.0

Comment: can you show a screenshot of the modifier itself?  If you're doing a Boolean difference, the object you use as the 'cutter' object will still appear in your scene unless you make it invisible, by the way

Comment: Thanks for an answer!   https://i.postimg.cc/0jJ5S20H/Screen-Shot-2021-05-24-at-19-19-56.png

Answer (score 3):

This is one of the most common mistakes new users of Boolean modifiers make, so I'll give a detailed example.

Add a cylinder to a scene with the default cube.  Scale the cylinder by .5 and move it +1 on the Z axis.  The result looks like this:

[image: default cube with a cylinder sticking out of the top]

Select the cube. Add a Boolean modifier and set the modifier object to the cylinder.

[image: Boolean modifier]

Nothing seems to have changed in the scene:

[image: Nothing seems different]

The Boolean modifier has worked, as you can see from the wire frame below, but the cylinder is still in the scene, so in solid mode it doesn't look like it worked:

[image: wire frame view]

By convention, when a object is used like the cylinder, it's referred to as a cutter.  The workflow for cutters has a few more steps usually:

- **Parent the cutter to the object it cuts.**  This allows you to move the cutter around, but if you move the object the cutter moves with it.
- **Remove the cutter from the render**.  If you leave the cutter in the render, then it will show up.  One way to remove it from the render is to put it into a separate collection and disable that collection.
- **Change the way the cutter looks in the viewport.**  You can go the the cutter's object properties; open the *Viewport Display* panel and change *Display As* to *Wire Frame*

Comment: In your case cylinder remove part of cube! why in my case boolean modifier live part of source solid object (red line in pic), and  i cant remove this parts ? why modifier dont make flat plane by the cut line ?    https://i.postimg.cc/yY7ssHJK/Screen-Shot-2021-05-24-at-20-24-00.png